# Opencart 2.3.0.2 black background image PNG

Tags: php, opencart

I have some issue with resized PNG images on Opencart 2.3.0.2. I think my code doesn't know how to work with PNG. Here is modified code of CATALOG/MODEL/TOOL/IMAGE.php

```
<?php
class ModelToolImage extends Model {
    public function resize($filename, $width, $height, $type = "f") {

        if (!file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $filename) || !is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
            return;
        }

        $info = pathinfo($filename);

        $extension = $info['extension'];

        $old_image = $filename;

        $new_image = 'cache/' . utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . $type .'.' . $extension;

        if (!file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image) || (filemtime(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image) > filemtime(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image))) {
            $path = '';           

            $directories = explode('/', dirname(str_replace('../', '', $new_image)));

            foreach ($directories as $directory) {
                $path = $path . '/' . $directory;

                if (!file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $path)) {
                    @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . $path, 0777);
                }
            }

            list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);

            if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {

                $scaleW = $width_orig/$width;
                $scaleH = $height_orig/$height;

                $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);

                if ($scaleH > $scaleW) {
                    $_height = $height * $scaleW;

                    $top_x = 0;
                    $top_y = ($height_orig - $_height) / 2;

                    $bottom_x = $width_orig;
                    $bottom_y = $top_y + $_height;

                    $image->crop($top_x, $top_y, $bottom_x, $bottom_y);
                } elseif ($scaleH < $scaleW) {
                    $_width = $width * $scaleH;

                    $top_x = ($width_orig - $_width) / 2;
                    $top_y = 0;

                    $bottom_x = $top_x + $_width;
                    $bottom_y = $height_orig;

                    $image->crop($top_x, $top_y, $bottom_x, $bottom_y);
                }

                $image->resize($width, $height, $type);
                $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
            } else {
                copy(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image, DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
            }
        }        

        if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
            return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $new_image;
        } else {
            return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $new_image;
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this code my png images have black background. Honestly I cant understand whats problem. 
I'm just learning PHP and can not fully understand what the problem is. 
And here is original code, where PNG images is okay and it is transparent

```
    <?php
class ModelToolImage extends Model {
    public function resize($filename, $width, $height) {
        if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
            if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . 'no_image.jpg')) {
                $filename = 'no_image.jpg';
            } elseif (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . 'no_image.png')) {
                $filename = 'no_image.png';
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }

        $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $image_old = $filename;
        $image_new = 'cache/' . utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.')) . '-' . (int)$width . 'x' . (int)$height . '.' . $extension;

        if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new) || (filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $image_old) > filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new))) {
            list($width_orig, $height_orig, $image_type) = getimagesize(DIR_IMAGE . $image_old);

            if (!in_array($image_type, array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF))) {
                return DIR_IMAGE . $image_old;
            }

            $path = '';

            $directories = explode('/', dirname($image_new));

            foreach ($directories as $directory) {
                $path = $path . '/' . $directory;

                if (!is_dir(DIR_IMAGE . $path)) {
                    @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . $path, 0777);
                }
            }

            if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {
                $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $image_old);
                $image->resize($width, $height);
                $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new);
            } else {
                copy(DIR_IMAGE . $image_old, DIR_IMAGE . $image_new);
            }
        }

        $imagepath_parts = explode('/', $image_new);
        $new_image = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', $imagepath_parts));

        if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
            return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $new_image;
        } else {
            return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $new_image;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this code from function 'resize' to 'crop' in system/library/image.php

```
    if ($this->mime == 'image/png') {
        imagealphablending($this->image, false);
        imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
        $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagecolortransparent($this->image, $background);
    } else {
        $background = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 255, 255);
    }
```